# Bitbucket - How to avoid differences between projects and files on versioning

Tags: git, bitbucket, versioning

Maybe this is a very simple question for who works with versioning for some time.
I started my first big project in team a little while ago and I'm having a lot of problems, it only has generated me headaches.. rebase, merge, pull, push, checkout, differences between so many things has made me break my head for hours, I've lost several modifications and had to delete the entire project to clone it from the beginning again.
So I'd like to ask you to guide me to use them correctly.

My coworkers often do a "pull" and the files dont look the same, often my modifications do not overwrite theirs and some files do not appear, what should be done at those times?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advice to use a GUI app for beginning with git. Something that visualizes the tree of commits and multiple branches of history. Tools like [GitUp](http://gitup.co/) or [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) on Mac, or their [alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/sourcetree/) on other platforms.

This visualization helps to answer quickly questions like "which branch code am I currently using now?" or "which commits do I have in my branch?".

A second important thing: always backup before doing any actions! Commit everything and make sure that nothing is left uncommitted (no untracked files, no changes). Then create a new branch with a good descriptive name like "backup/X-N" (where X is the name of the task you're working on and N is the number of the backup). And then switch back to the previous branch. This way nothing gets lost by unintentional git commands.

Thirdly, start small, learn commands one by one. For example `git pull` is actually `git fetch` (from a remote repository) + `git merge` (current local branch with the remote corresponding branch), so learn `git merge X` first where X is some local branch.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, i'll try to use SourceTree, always heared about it. But my real problem is to know how it really works, i don't know what is branches and i always make commits, we cant push codes without commiting.. I dont know how to back from a backup point on git. but i'll see about it, thanks a lot!